# Find the optimal value that minimize a function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima, frobenius-method

I am trying to solve the following equation 
$min_{P} F(P)=||P^TX−P^TYZ−LP^TX+A||^2_F$
with $P$ is a $(d,p)$ matrix ,$X$ a $(d,n)$ matrix ,$Y$ a $(d,m)$ matrix ,$L$ a $(p,p)$matrix , $Z$ a $(m,n)$ matrix and $A$ a $(p,n)$ matix.

When computing the derivative I end up with :
$\frac{∂F}{∂P}=2(XM−YZM−XML)$ with $M=(P^TX−P^TYZ−LP^TX+A)^T$.

But I stuck here ,I dont know How to extrate the optimal value of $P$

Please can someone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your gradient calculation looks correct, so let's continue from there.

For convenience define the matrix $$W=X-YZ$$so that $$M=W^TP-X^TPL^T+A^T$$Setting the gradient to zero and rearranging terms yields
$$\eqalign{
WM &= XML \cr
WW^TP-WX^TPL^T+WA^T &= XW^TPL-XX^TPL^TL+XA^TL \cr
WW^TP-WX^TPL^T-XW^TPL+XX^TPL^TL &= XA^TL-WA^T \cr
}$$
Vectorize this equation in order to isolate and solve for $P$
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(XA^TL-WA^T) &= (I\otimes WW^T-L\otimes WX^T-L^T\otimes XW^T+L^TL\otimes XX^T)\,{\rm vec}(P) \cr
{\rm vec}(B) &= C\,{\rm vec}(P) \cr
{\rm vec}(P) &= C^{+}{\rm vec}(B) \cr
}$$
I have no idea if the coefficient matrix $C$ is invertible, so I used the Moore-Penrose inverse.

Comment: @ greg , before writing the last line, you must prove that $vec(B)\in im(C)$; if yes, the last line is a particular solution of the equation above; you must write the general solution of this equation and see if the value of $F(P)$ depends on the chosen solution $P$.

Comment: Thank you greg for your solution

Comment: @loupblanc can you tell me what do you mean by $vec(B)∈im(C)$ ..What $im(C)$ actually means

Comment: @ abdallah , $im(C)$ is the image of the function $C$.

Comment: Let $Z=(L\otimes X^T-I\otimes W^T),\,\,$ then @greg's vectorized equation can be written as$$Z^TZ\,p=Z^TK\,a$$whose solution is the same as my own.

Comment: @ lynn , I give a sketch of  the reasoning. 1. $im(Z^TZ)=im(Z^T)$ and consequently $p$ exists. 2. The general solution is $p=(Z^TZ)^+Z^TKa+(I-(Z^TZ)^+Z^TZ)w$ where $w$ is an arbitrary vector. 3. The value of $F(p)$ does not depend on the choice of the arbitrary $w$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of formulating the problem is to find the least-squares solution of 
$$\eqalign{X^TPL^T - W^TP &= A^T \cr}$$where $W=(X-YZ)$.

Vectorize the equation and solve it via the pseudoinverse
$$\eqalign{
  (L\otimes X^T-I\otimes W^T)p &= Ka \cr
  p &= (L\otimes X^T-I\otimes W^T)^{\dagger}Ka \cr
}$$where $K$ is the Kronecker commutation matrix, $a={\rm vec}(A)$, $Ka={\rm vec}(A^T)$, and $p={\rm vec}(P)$